# Android - Reference object in separate view

Tags: android, button, textview

I am doing an Android App.  I want to use a button in one view to set the text of a text view in a different view.  How do I reference the button in the other view?

Comment: What have you tried? Can you post some code? Do you have a reference to the views?

Comment: You can use ``Activity.findViewById`` for any view/button currently visible in current layout. If by _different view_ you mean different Activity, it's a different story though.

Answer (score 1):

If the views containing button and textView are in the same layout that you inflated in onCreate() method using setContentView(R.layout.layout), then you can simply use:

```
 Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
```

Else, if the textView/Button view is not in the layout that is inflated in onCreate() method, you need to inflate the other view first and then reference the textView/Button as follows:

```
   LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext());
   View view = (View)inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout2, null);
   Button button = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
   //add code for button
  // or   TextView tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
```